# How to find out magento filesystem user

Tags: cli

I came across a permission problem and need to find out what is the default user for magento filesystem.

How do i figure out which user is the owner of magento filesystem? How can i do it from the command line?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

That's too simple. Just **`cd`** to folder just above Magento's root and run **`ls -la`** command. It will list files and folders with owner and permission details.

**For example:** If your Magento lies under **`/var/www/html/projects`** folder, then run below command:

```
cd /var/www/html/projects
ls -la
```

If you want to know which user is currently running apache processes, then type following command in command window:

```
ps -ef | egrep '(httpd|apache2|apache)' | grep -v `whoami` | grep -v root | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

Please let me know if you need more details.